# Determine what color is this RGB tuple

Tags: python, image, opencv, colors

I'm running a test over a large amount of images, and for each extracting RGB values of its most dominant colors. What I'm trying to do now is determine what color is each value. For example, I want it to return "Blue" for (42, 71, 101) or "purple" for (187, 121, 133). It's enough for me to get a result of red, orange, yellow, green, blue or purple (no pinks or turquoises needed :))

I saw the [post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/04/opencv-python-color-detection/) about OpenCV and Python color detection, but it's not exactly what I need because it creates a mask, and I'm looking for a simpler output.

The difficult part is to determine what are the upper and lower boundaries, because I need it to work for any RGB value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Side note: In general it is better to use HSV color space for image segmentation since the B, G and R channels are all correlated with the amount of lighting. Also don't forget that OpenCV uses the BGR format, not RGB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it 3 different ways.

1) Via matplotlib

```
import matplotlib #pip install  matplotlib
print matplotlib.colors.cnames["blue"]   # prints u'#0000FF'
```

If you want convert from hex to rgb you can use following function:

```
def hex_to_rgb(hexcode):
   rgb = tuple(map(ord,hexcode[1:].decode('hex')))
   return rgb
```

2) with  this [github](https://gist.github.com/jdiscar/9144764)

3) You can also use webcolors package [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webcolors/1.3)